# Error al mostrar los constructores en el navegador de NetBeans

Tags: java, clase, diseño-de-clases

buenos días.
Tengo el siguiente problema: Al crear una clase, con sus atributos, metodos, constructores, etc... No me muestra los constructores en el navegador.
Así debería verse:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y así es cómo me aparece a mí:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi clase Punto, tiene la siguiente forma:

```
public class Punto implements Serializable{
    
    //Zona de atributos
    private int x;
    private int y;
    
    //Constructores
    public void Punto(int x, int y){ //Constructor con parametros
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
    public void Punto (Punto p) { //Copia
        this.x= p.x;
        this.y= p.y;
    }
    public void Punto(){ //Constructor sin parametros
        
    }

    //Getters y Setters
    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public void setX(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public void setY(int y) {
        this.y = y;
    }
    
    //Mostrar y toString
    public void mostrar(){
        System.out.println("El punto corresponde a" + x + "," +y );
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "El Punto es:\n" + "Cordenada x: " + x + "\nCoordenada y: " + y + "\n";
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Pero sí te aparecen. Las dos imagenes son prácticamente iguales. ¿Lo que deseas es que aparezcan con un rombo?

Comment: Sí, es lo que quiero, que me aparezcan los constructores con un rombo

Comment: Pensé que podía ser una cuestión de configuración de interfaz, pero el problema es tu código, ahí dejé la solución.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El constructor no lleva el modificador `void`. De hecho, no lleva ningún modificador. Es precisamente esa la diferencia con un método no constructor. Al usar `void`, estás haciendo un set, es decir **actualizando los valores de un objeto ya creado**.

```
//Constructores
public Punto(int x, int y){ //Constructor con parametros
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}
public Punto (Punto p) { //Copia
    this.x= p.x;
    this.y= p.y;
}
public Punto(){ //Constructor sin parametros
    
}
```

Comment: Gracias, tenias razón.